# Giving Print Job Using PHP

Tags: php, zebra-printers

I am using Jzebra for giving print job from browser to printer.

I could list the printers name from local machine using jzebra but i want to know any other identification like printer ip address or anything else to detect the printer and also i want to give print using that.

I tried `php_printer.dll` but it doesn't work for me and also i spoke to my server support. They also didnt give positive result.

I want to get the printer identification and using that i want to give print job to printer using php or jzebra.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask the people at Jzebra that question?

Comment: if its a very urgent case then in that case you can go for javascript window.print();

Comment: i am not gonna use this command because in my concept the print job will execute in background without using dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You can read some helpful comments put on similar questions available at

[PHP to Zebra Printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766228/php-to-zebra-printer?rq=1)

[Printing to printers in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841720/printing-to-printers-in-php)

[Print directly to network printer using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956143/print-directly-to-network-printer-using-php?rq=1)

Additionally you can browse to http://php.net/manual/en/book.printer.php for printing support and function in PHP.

Hope it helps

Comment: php_printer concept is completely not working for me. Even it will not work in server also. i discussed with support team.