# Networked Zebra Label Printer using PHP/AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, zebra-printers

I have been tasked with figuring out how to get our zebra label printers(mostly the 420t models) to print over the network from calls in one of our PHP applications.  I've come up with a couple of ideas but wanted to run it past people more knowledgeable than I am before I start down one path or the other.

1. Setup a machine to be a print server which has the zebra on USB as the default printer.  I'd have to write some sort of print queue script or something to run on this machine.
2. Get a zebra printer with a network port and directly send print requests to it.  I have seen a couple of other SO questions about it and it seems to require sending in the RAW over sockets.  From the answers on these questions it seemed like there were some issues with doing this.
3. Send the print request via FTP somehow as mentioned in a few places.
4. Use either 1 or 2 with the LPR library.

What do you guys suggest?

Comment: Don't know if you already looked, but check this link out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766228/php-to-zebra-printer?rq=1

Comment: It depends entirely on if you're using ZPL or if you're sending the printer images.  Our PHP application uses the image method, and it just sends the print job off to CUPS using `lpr` like it was any other printer.

Answer (score 0):

I use intersively the second solution at work, ie using network enabled printers, and sending them (via cURL to the printers IP) data from a .prn file with my replacements.

The models we use are [G4K20d](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/printers/desktop/advanced-desktop-printers.html).