# Emulate EPL2 Printer Serverside

Tags: printing, emulation, zpl, epl

There have been a few questions on SO about emulating a ZPL printers etc, but all of them require some native application or a an app.
(see here: [Emulate ZPL printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066789/emulate-zpl-printer/33066790#33066790) )

My Question:
**Is it possible to emulate the EPL2 printer language to render a .png on a unix machine via code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to code an app to do it. As far as I know, Zebra hasn't released the fonts built into the printer though, so it would be very tedious...

Comment: I already implemented a EPL2 renderer in PHP7, sadly I can't release it as composer package since it's made for a client of mine.