# Barcode wasn't printed as many as the Request

Tags: emulation, zebra-printers, zpl, barcode-printing, zpl-ii

I was able to [print raw ZPL commands from PHP directly to the printer](https://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-print-raw-Zebra-ZPL-commands-from-PHP-directly-to-the-client-printer/), except that I can't print more than 1 label at once after [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) update to [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) on the [TLP 2844-Z](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=TLP+2844-Z&oq=TLP+2844-Z) printer and my first time when installing [WebClientPrint Processor (WCPP)](https://www.neodynamic.com/downloads/wcpp/wcpp2.aspx) in [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10). When I was trying to [emulate ZPL printer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60148675/36548307) in the [ZPL Printer app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zpl-printer/phoidlklenidapnijkabnfdgmadlcmjo) it also happened. The only exception was when I try this on the [mac](/questions/tagged/mac) Safari browser, it's doing fine.

---

Working request script (still working in Safari, and previously in all other browser):

```
for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
     javascript:jsWebClientPrint.print('useDefaultPrinter=' + $('#useDefaultPrinter').attr('checked') + '&printerName=' + $('#installedPrinterName').val() + '&param=' + rows[i].value);
}
```

What's preventing me was the permission asking:

[image: wcp]

on Chrome weren't generated as many time as the request were (which aren't the problem on Safari).

---

Example when request were 2:
[image: request]

it only ask for [permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNu4Q.png) once, resulting (only 1 label printed):

[image: result]

when it supposed to be (2 labels printed):

[image: expected]

I was able to reproduce the above by using the following script:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  var url = ('useDefaultPrinter=' + $('#useDefaultPrinter').attr('checked') + '&printerName=' + $('#installedPrinterName').val() + '&param=' + rows[i].value);
  window.open('webclientprint:' + domain + url);
}
```

Which aren't ideal since many tabs would be generated only to print, where previously you don't need any new tab to do the same.

---

Any idea how to solve this? So that it would print as many as the request ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to solve this was to make each request on a separate tab and closed the tab once it's executed. To make it simple I make it into a separate function.

**Request script** changed into:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  if (i > 0)
    delayPrint(rows[i], i); // separate function
  else
    javascript: jsWebClientPrint.print('useDefaultPrinter=' + $('#useDefaultPrinter').attr('checked') + '&printerName=' + $('#installedPrinterName').val() + '&param=' + rows[i].value);
}
```

**separate function** used for delaying request and to make each request on a separate tab and closed the tab once it's executed:

```
function delayPrint(data, interval) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var wnd =   window.open('webclientprint:' + domain + ('useDefaultPrinter=' + $('#useDefaultPrinter').attr('checked') + '&printerName=' + $('#installedPrinterName').val() + '&param=' + rows[i].value));
    setTimeout(function() {
      wnd.close(); // close once it's done
    }, 1000);
  }, interval * 3000);
}
```