# Zpl printer receive fragmented data from Java application

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, printing, zpl

#### Background

I am trying to create a java application to send ZPL command to a ZPL printer and get a label printed.
I set up a ZPL emulator(https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zpl-printer/phoidlklenidapnijkabnfdgmadlcmjo) by following this post : [Emulate ZPL printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066789/emulate-zpl-printer)

#### Issue

1. After setting the emulator up and add it as zpl printer via mac Printer&Scanner ,
   [image]

I try to use lp command to print it. it is stable the reliable:

```
lp -o "raw" -q1 -d zpl <<< "^XA\n^FO50,60^A0,40^FDWorld Best Griddle^FS\n^FO60,120^BY3^BCN,60,,,,A^FD1234ABC^FS\n^FO25,25^GB380,200,2^FS\n^XZ"
```

[image]

2. However, my use case is send the command to a printer remotely on the network, Therefore I need to create a java application to send the Zpl command to the printer. It succeeds initially, then it randomly get splitted: 
   java code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class TCPClient
{
    public static void main (String argv[]) throws Exception
    {

        Socket clientSocket=new Socket("127.0.0.1",9100);

        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream() );
        try {
            outToServer.writeBytes("^XA\n^FO50,60^A0,40^FDWorld Best Griddle^FS\n^FO60,120^BY3^BCN,60,,,,A^FD1234ABC^FS\n^FO25,25^GB380,200,2^FS\n^XZ");
                
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        outToServer.flush();
        outToServer.close();
        clientSocket.close();
//        outToServer.flush();

    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

**So quite often, it succeeds once and then following 2 or 3 printing get fragmented or failed. I suspect it might be the socket TCP fragmentation issue. or there any socket option I can configure? But not sure how to solve it. Can anyone help here?**

### Update:

I try to use wireshark. The issue resides in the TCP package size:

For lp command, everything is sent as one single pack:
[image]

As for java app, it is broken down into smaller packs for some reason.
[image]

But I still don't know how to configure the pack size. Also it confuses me a lot why Java app will break the data packet to **like 1 byte or two byte sized?**

Comment: Basically now my question is how we can diable TCP fragmentation in java socket programming

Comment: Like limiting the data content to one single TCP packet

Comment: It has nothing to do with the size of the TCP packets. TCP is not a message oriented protocol but rather a stream protocol, so no successful protocol built on top of TCP depends on receiving individual packets of any particular size.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Then it might be the issue of the ZPL emulator? like it just cannot handle the tcp message properly. Like not knowing how to assemble the packet together

Comment: I think the issue is that I didn't use LPR protocol...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a wrong method to send printing job. I'm not sure `lp` command uses `Socket` connection. Try calling `lp` from Java using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`:

```
String cmd = "lp -o \"raw\" -q1 -d zpl <<< \"^XA\n^FO50,60^A0,40^FDWorld Best Griddle^FS\n^FO60,120^BY3^BCN,60,,,,A^FD1234ABC^FS\n^FO25,25^GB380,200,2^FS\n^XZ\"";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format(cmd));
```

Comment: But my use case is that printer is remote. Can only be identified by IP.

Comment: @Stan that doesn't matter. Add a remote printer to your system the same way you add a local one and send jobs to the printer through your system.  You can also use `lp` command to add printers: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-7229/printsetup-42445/index.html

Comment: ok, my use case is a microservice will be deployed into GCP cloud run(serverless). And printers are on-prem whose IPs are assigned by DHCP. It means microservice has to reach out to the DHCP server first to get a IP for printer then send the command to the printer directly.

Comment: @Stan I think this is a completely different problem. Try calling your printer remotely first. If you can do that, you can always add new remote printer to your system from java using the guide above and immediately call it via LPR protocol.

Comment: How can we add the printer to cloud run? we cannot configure each time we receive a print request, right?

Comment: @Stan you can run preconfigured docker container